# Adding multiple relationships using WITH, WHERE, and UNWIND

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data in the following structure:

```
{"id": "1", "name": "A. I. Lazarev", "org": "United States Department of State", "tags": [{"t": "Infrared"}, {"t": "Near-infrared spectroscopy"}, {"t": "Infrared astronomy"}, {"t": "Data collection"}], "pubs": [{"i": "1542417502", "r": 6}], }
{"id": "2", "name": "Stevan Spremo", "tags": [{"t": "Micro-g environment"}, {"t": "Antibiotics"}, {"t": "Bacteriology"}], "pubs": [{"i": "222163962", "r": 0}], }
{"id": "3", "name": "Bricchi G", "pubs": [{"i": "2417067698", "r": 1}, {"i": "2406980973", "r": 1}]}
```

Some of the rows have tags, some have organizations, some have both, and some have neither.

I'd like to add relationships between (1) authors and tags, (2) authors and organizations, and (3) authors and publications. I have the publications as nodes already, so it should be fairly straightforward to get (3) once I get (1) and (2).

I have been trying to use the following code:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"CALL apoc.load.json('file:/test.txt') YIELD value AS q RETURN q",
"UNWIND q.id as id
CREATE (a:Author {id:id, name:q.name, citations:q.n_citation, publications:q.n_pubs})
WITH q, a
UNWIND q.tags as tags
MERGE (t:Tag {{name: tags.t}})
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_TAGS]->(t)
WITH q, a
WHERE q.org is not null
MERGE (o:Organization {name: q.org})
CREATE (a)-[:AFFILIATED_WITH]->(o)",
{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:false})
```

The tags and the organizations show up multiple times in the data, but should only have one node each, so I have used `MERGE` to create unique nodes for these.

The problem with the following code is that it creates duplicate `AFFILIATED_WITH` relationships -  it actually creates the same number of `AFFILIATED_WITH` relationships as there are tags.

How can I change the cypher query so that it isn't creating duplicate relationships?

Comment: Why don't you use `merge` for your relationships?

Comment: There should only be one author organization relationship in the dataset. Same for the author tags organizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this clause:

```
UNWIND q.tags as tags
```

your query will have as many data rows as the number of tags for the current `q` (each row will have `q, a, id, tags` values). The subsequent operations will be performed once per data row. That is why you are creating too many `AFFILIATED_WITH` relationships.

To solve your issue, you have to reduce the number of data rows appropriately, at the appropriate time (and this will also speed up your processing, since unnecessarily repeated operations will be avoided). In your case, you can just change the second `WITH q, a` clause to `WITH DISTINCT q, a`:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "CALL apoc.load.json('file:///test.txt') YIELD value AS q RETURN q",
  "CREATE (a:Author {id:q.id, name:q.name, citations:q.n_citation, publications:q.n_pubs})
   WITH q, a
   UNWIND q.tags as tags
   MERGE (t:Tag {name: tags.t})
   CREATE (a)-[:HAS_TAGS]->(t)
   WITH DISTINCT q, a
   WHERE q.org is not null
   MERGE (o:Organization {name: q.org})
   CREATE (a)-[:AFFILIATED_WITH]->(o)",
  {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:false}
)
```

I have also simplified the query by removing the unnecessary `UNWIND q.id as id` clause, and fixed some syntax issues.

[UPDATED]

If you want to add the `AUTHORED` relationships (as requested in the comments to this answer), you should do that *before* you create the `AFFILIATED_WITH` relationships -- since the `WHERE q.org is not null` clause would filter out some `q` nodes. Also, whenever you use `CREATE` to create a relationship, Cypher requires that you specify a *direction* for the relationship.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "CALL apoc.load.json('file:///test.txt') YIELD value AS q RETURN q",
  "CREATE (a:Author {id:q.id, name:q.name, citations:q.n_citation, publications:q.n_pubs})
   WITH q, a
   UNWIND q.tags as tags
   MERGE (t:Tag {name: tags.t})
   CREATE (a)-[:HAS_TAGS]->(t)
   WITH DISTINCT q, a
   UNWIND q.pubs as pubs
   MERGE (p:Quanta {id: pubs.i})
   CREATE (a)-[r:AUTHORED {rank: pubs.r}]->(p)
   WITH q, a
   WHERE q.org is not null
   MERGE (o:Organization {name: q.org})
   CREATE (a)-[:AFFILIATED_WITH]->(o)",
  {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:false}
)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I also wanted to add relationships to existing papers with the following:

WITH q, a
UNWIND q.pubs as pubs
MERGE (p:Quanta {id: pubs.i})
CREATE (a)-[r:AUTHORED {rank: pubs.r}]-(p).

I tried putting this before, after, and in between the two other WITH clauses, but it doesn't seem to be working. 

If you prefer I can open a new question, but I figured it's worth asking here!